# How does SequenceMatcher.ratio works in difflib

Tags: python, string, string-matching, similarity

I was trying out python's difflib module and I came across `SequenceMatcher`. So, I tried the following examples but couldn't understand what is happening.

```
>>> SequenceMatcher(None,"abc","a").ratio()
0.5

>>> SequenceMatcher(None,"aabc","a").ratio()
0.4

>>> SequenceMatcher(None,"aabc","aa").ratio()
0.6666666666666666
```

Now, according to the [ratio](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio):

> Return a measure of the sequences' similarity as a float in the range
>   [0, 1]. Where `T` is the total number of elements in both sequences, and
>   `M` is the number of matches, this is `2.0*M / T`.

so, for my cases:

1. `T=4` and `M=1` so ratio `2*1/4 = 0.5`
2. `T=5` and `M=2` so ratio `2*2/5 = 0.8`
3. `T=6` and `M=1` so ratio `2*1/6.0 = 0.33`

According to my understanding `T = len(aabc) + len(a)` and `M=2` because `a` comes twice in `aabc`.

So, where am I getting wrong what am I missing.?

[Here](http://pyxr.sourceforge.net/PyXR/c/python24/lib/difflib.py.html#0602) is the source code of `SequenceMatcher.ratio()`

Answer (score 6):

You've got the first case right. In the second case, only one `a` from `aabc` matches, so *M* = 1. In the third example, both `a`s match so *M* = 2.

[P.S.: you're referring to the ancient Python 2.4 source code. The current source code is at [hg.python.org](http://hg.python.org/cpython/).]

Comment: But why only one `a` from `aabc` matches. I believe it should match both `a's`. In third example both `a's` match but is `aa` matched to `aa` alone or it is first matched to `a` and than the next `a` making it M=2. It is still not clear to me.

Comment: @Noob: because in the second case, there's only on `a` in the second string to match with, while in the third there are two, so only the `bc` part matches nothing. Try matching `a` with `aa`.

Comment: Matches actually stands for _character_ matches. So the string "a" can only do one match, because it has only a single character that can create a match. "aa" has two characters, and thus provides two matches.

Comment: Hey is there any way to get the number of matches?

Comment: Much too late, but still: you could do `T=len(a)+len(b)` `M=T*ratio()/2`.

Answer (score 0):

never too late...

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

texto1 = 'BRASILIA~DISTRITO FEDERAL, DF'
texto2 = 'BRASILIA-DISTRITO FEDERAL, '

tamanho_texto1 = len(texto1)
tamanho_texto2 = len(texto2)
tamanho_tot = tamanho_texto1 + tamanho_texto2

tot = 0
if texto1 <= texto2:
    for x in range(len(texto1)):
        y = texto1[x]

        if y in texto2:
            tot += 1
else:
    for x in range(len(texto2)):
        y = texto2[x]

        if y in texto1:
            tot += 1
            
print('sequenceM = ',SequenceMatcher(None, texto1, texto2).ratio())
print('Total calculado = ',2*tot/tamanho_tot)
```

sequenceM =  0.9285714285714286

Total calculado =  0.9285714285714286

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).